# Calculating Correlation after removing zeros

Tags: r

I have two named vectors A and B. I have to calculate correlation between them after removing entries which are 0 in both A and B. That is, if for a certain name 'Sample1', the value in both A and B are 0, then I would like to remove that entry from the correlation calculation.

Is there a way to do this easily? I am using `cor(A, B)` to calculate correlation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
# construct vectors
set.seed(1234)
A <- sample(0:10, 100, replace=T)
B <- sample(0:10, 100, replace=T)

# remove elements of A and B where both are 0
cor(A[A != 0 | B != 0], B[A !=0 | B != 0])
```

Or, more coherently to myself at the moment

```
cor(A[!(A == 0 & B == 0)], B[!(A ==0 & B == 0)])
```

Answer (score 4):

If your data was in a data.frame, `df`, you could use the `subset` function:

```
df <- data.frame(A, B)
with(subset(df, !(A == 0 & B == 0)), cor(A,B))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is with `rowSums`, create a logical index and do the `cor`

```
with(df[!!rowSums(df),], cor(A,B))
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need to tweek your code slightly to:

```
cor(A, B, na.rm=T)
```

na.rm=T tells it to remove missing values.